# Alternatives to debug a docker + gunicorn app in production

Tags: python, debugging, docker, uwsgi, gunicorn

I'm kinda curious of what alternatives people are using to debug applications that are running live with either uwsgi or gunicorn in a Docker container.

The scenario would be, a bug that cannot be reproduced locally, and it seems to be happening only in production / staging.

From what I've seen, some people seem to suggest running a second instance of the application in the server, and use ssh tunnel to be able to debug. Add some traces and once the problem is spotted, kill the second instance and go back to normal.

Another option would be to use something like rpdb or pudb as stated [here](http://kartowicz.com/dryobates/2016-09/debugging_gunicorn_on_docker_with_pudb/) but this, as usual, means having to add traces wherever we want to add a breakpoint, as well as restarting gunicorn or Docker container to take these changes into account.

Last option I can think of is using post-mortem, which is good also but as usual, means restarting the server, since I have to include the traces so if an expection happens, the debugger will show up...

The less intrusive to me seems first option, since I can have 2 instances of same app running at the same time, and after debugging I can just shut down the debugging one and the original one is left unaltered...

Any other options?